# integrating mongodb with cloud-hosted elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, heroku

I have a cloud-hosted mongo database and also a cloud-hosted elasticsearch instance. The mongoDB predates the ES. ElasticSearch is what I am trying to configure right now.

I've read that mongo-connector is one of the ways to do it, but this requires a python service running. I am using Heroku for my API. Does this mean I need to spin up a python dyno for the mongo-connector?

Alternatively, are there any node.js connectors that I can integrate into my API codebase?

I will select the best answer based on the balance between simplicity in terms of implementation and also its robustness. The answer can address any of the two questions I've asked as they both solve the same problem for me.

Comment: Combining multiple questions is not recommended as it may be hard to pick the correct answer that answers only part of the question.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks for the pointer. I've edited the question to emphasise on the fact that I have one problem but open to solutions that come from either 'methods'.